# Proper implementation of libspotify get_audio_buffer_stats callback

Tags: c++, spotify, libspotify

Can anyone help decipher the correct implementation of the libspotify get_audio_buffer_stats callback. Specifically, we are supposed to populate a sp_audio_buffer_stats buffer, consisting of samples and stutter?

According to the Docs:

`int   samples` - Samples in buffer.

`int    stutter` - Number of stutters (audio dropouts) since last query.

I'm wondering about "samples." What exactly is this referring to?

The music playback  (audio_delivery) callback has a num_frames variable, but then you have the issue of audio format (channels and/or sample_rate).

Is it correct to set "samples" to total amount of "num_frames" currently in my buffer? Or do I need to run some math based on total "num_samples", "channels", and "sample_rate"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the number of frames in your output buffer. I.e. `int samples` is slightly misnamed and should probably be called `int frames` instead.

Comment: After a bit of testing this appears to be correct. Also note that the "stutter" variable should be reset to 0 after each call. I was **NOT** doing that, and ended up with some weird behavior. Thanks andoma.